# sql increment line numbering

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with oracle and I need incremental line numbering each time i run `query`. I know usually solution is using `rownum` but:

`query 1`:

```
1  1st row
2  2nd row
3  3rd row
```

I will now sort `query` by some value and ouput should be

```
1 3rd row
2 1st row
3 2nd row
```

How can I achive that kind of behaveour?

EDIT:
I think my question wasnt clear. I do not need solution using `rownum`, what i need is simple `number` at each line of my `query` it should allways be in `sequential` order (1,2,3,4,5).

So:

I run a `query` and my initial results are

```
Line nr     Some value
1            line 1
2            line 2
3            line 3
4            line 4
```

Now i will run same `query` with different `order by`

```
Line nr     Some value
1            line 4
2            line 3 
3            line 2
4            line 1
```

Note: I  am interested in column **Line nr**

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by some value)`

Comment: @Tagyoureit - Do you want a query which will change the order of rows for every subsequent run?

Comment: Please take another look at my questing i have added additional explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY some_value ) id,
       value
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY some_value
```

or:

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS id,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT value
  FROM   your_table
  ORDER BY some_value
)
```

**Example**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( value, some_value, some_other_value ) AS
SELECT 'Line 1', 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Line 2', 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Line 3', 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Line 4', 1, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY some_value ) id,
       value
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY some_value
```

**Output 1**:

```
        ID VALUE
---------- ------
         1 Line 4 
         2 Line 3 
         3 Line 2 
         4 Line 1
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT ROWNUM AS id,
       value
FROM   (
  SELECT value
  FROM   your_table
  ORDER BY some_other_value
)
```

**Output 2**:

```
        ID VALUE
---------- ------
         1 Line 3 
         2 Line 1 
         3 Line 4 
         4 Line 2
```

**Query 3 - Using `DESC` ordering**:

(Remember to update the ordering in **both** places)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY some_other_value DESC ) id,
       value
FROM   your_table
ORDER BY some_other_value DESC;
```

**Output 3**:

```
        ID VALUE
---------- ------
         1 Line 2 
         2 Line 4 
         3 Line 1 
         4 Line 3
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but its not what i am looking for. Please take another look at my original question i have explained it a little more into detail.

Comment: Please take a look at the example I have added to my answer - it exactly matches your requirements (i.e. `id` is the equivalent of your `line_nr`).

Comment: Taking from your example (Qerry 1) if i run it as u said i will get correct numbering. But if i take your solution and change order by to desc id (line_nr) will be in descending order. I want it to stay in ASC order all the time. Line number should be in ASC order.

Comment: @Tagyoureit See update 3 - you need to change it to `DESC` ordering in both places. Query 2 is much easier to maintain with respect to changing order as there is only a single `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: Ok i really feel and look dumb now. Thank you for pointing out my mistake and thanks for your time.